How to substitute URLs?
I'm trying to search a replace an URL in a html file but it gives me strange errors.
Typing :%s|https://example.com|https://placehold.co/64|g correctly highlights the previous URL but when running it, I get E486: Pattern not found: <br>. It seems like it's trying to apply the previous substitution (I replaced <br> with something else just before).
Replacing basic text works fine. I tried using nomagic to disable regex but it didn't work.

Unrelated but :set nomagic does not disable regex. You will just have to escape some more special characters, that's all.

I would do:
:%s!https://example.com!https://placehold.co/64!g

Or even better:
:%s!\Vhttps://example.com!https://placehold.co/64!g

To avoid to match https://exampleOcom since without the \V flag the . match any character (e.g. O in the example).
More information with :help /magic
The | is a very special character in the Vim command used to chain command. You should not use it a substitute separator (I prefer using ! when not using /).
For pattern separator you can use any character but:

an alphanumeric character,
\,
" or
|

More information with :help pattern-separator

Thank you. I got used to using | in sed where it didn't matter, so I didn't even question it.

Thanks for the feedback :-) Vim has it own dark corner ;-)

It might be good to move the bit about pattern-separator further up into the answer; the lede is a bit buried
